# "Too many method references" issue

Tags: android, dex

I have a project with a lot of jar libs, When I build my project, the concole output
"trouble writing output: Too many method references: 67715; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option."
But I can't find where to set this option. please help me.
I just want to know how to use this option in eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508477/android-my-application-is-too-large-and-gives-unable-to-execute-dex-method-id

Comment: 15508477 isn't really applicable to his specific question about the --multi-dex option. You can however find a bit more info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955297/how-can-i-use-the-multi-dex-option

Comment: To use multiple dex is kinda painful, it's probably better to look for alternative solutions first before going this route. For example, you can use Proguard to strip away unused methods, or manually remove unused .class/.java(if available) files from the jar libs included in your project (if the respective license for the jar allows for that)