# Gradle Android build: how to specify options for the Android command line build tools used..?

Tags: android, build, gradle

When I use Gradle to build my Android app, it executes a whole chain of Android command line build tools like 'dx' to build my apk.

Those command line tools all have 'options'. I would like to specify some of these options within my Gradle build. How is this possible?

Comment: I know that I can add some predefined options like so: android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental false
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
    }
}

Still. I was looking to be able to define all the options tools like dx offer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25975702/231078), which shows that you can use `dexTask.additionalParameters` to pass additional arguments to the `dx` tool.  An easy way to get access to the `dexTask` is from the variants list:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    Dex dexTask = variant.dex
    if (dexTask.additionalParameters == null) dex.additionalParameters = []
    // This is just an example:
    dexTask.additionalParameters += '--help'
    // you could use others, such as '--multi-dex', or anything else that appears in the '--help' output.
}
```

From the [source of `AndroidBuilder.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/1cb9df6e3a9999cbf71e45b17daa4cc01a894b3c/build-system/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/core/AndroidBuilder.java#1523), you can see which commandline arguments are already being added to the `dx` tool before appending your `additionalParameters`.