# Gradle - "enforceUniquePackageName" deprecated with version 3.0.0+?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
android {
    enforceUniquePackageName = false
}
```

"enforceUniquePackageName" works with the gradle version:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
}
```

However, if I change the gradle version to 3.0.0

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
}
```

I get:

```
Could not set unknown property 'enforceUniquePackageName' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension. Open File
```

If 'enforceUniquePackageName' property is deprecated, then what would be the alternative option?

Comment: If I had to guess, they got rid of it entirely with no replacement. [Error messages from two years ago said that this feature was temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28417283/115145).

Comment: Noooooo!!! They removed such a nice feature. I now need to rename packages and all JNI method names with it.

Comment: They talked about this briefly at the '18 I/O...
IIRC it was either this session - https://events.google.com/io2018/schedule/?section=may-8&sid=72e67d84-07ba-4535-9a71-95adc3417436&topic=android%26play&type=sessions - or this one - https://events.google.com/io2018/schedule/?section=may-8&sid=a6aca269-b30c-456f-a730-65b2431f2ef4&topic=android%26play&type=sessions

Answer (score 1):

This was renamed in AGP 3.4:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#agp-7-1-stable-known-issues
to uniquePackageNames