# Can't import "CastVideos-android" to Andr Studio: Could not set unknown property 'enforceUniquePackageName'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, chromecast

The error message:  Could not set unknown property 'enforceUniquePackageName' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.

The only relevant search result I found was [Gradle - "enforceUniquePackageName" deprecated with version 3.0.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446087/gradle-enforceuniquepackagename-deprecated-with-version-3-0-0)
which notes that older Gradle versions will work with this.

I'd like to know how others have got around this issue.

Comment: It was also stated in this [link](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/issues/55) that after Gradle v3.0.0+, `enforceUniquePackageName` has been deprecated. You can either, not update the gradle, or remove that line. The app should build regardless.