# How to solve A library uses the same package as this project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do I fix this?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':androidmapsutils:processReleaseResources'.
> Error: A library uses the same package as this project: com.google.maps.android
```

Comment: try using `enforceUniquePackageName=false`. look https://stackoverflow.com/a/33103389/5241603

Answer (score 1):

If you use `enforceUniquePackageName=false` you'll eventually stumble upon this bug -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: ... BuildConfig.class

and in order to fix that you'll have to check if some of your dependencies have multidex as a dependency in it and exclude it, for example the Facebook SDK -

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:+') { 
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex' 
    }
```

You can refer to this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417283/android-studio-using-a-library-and-project-with-the-same-package-name/33103389#33103389) and this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37013785)

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: I added my two bits to the referenced Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just read it, but it's a slightly different problem here, since the library uses the same dependency as the project utilizing the library and hence the duplicate name errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile project(':library')
```

Check included package name

```
com.google.maps.android.
```