# java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2 when using Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

When I try to compile my app I get a following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

If I get rid of Facebook Android SDK it compiles without a problem.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21 //tried 19 and 22 changing targetSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion accordingly
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

...

}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1' //tried older versions as well
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your build with --debug or --info flags?

Comment: please check out my post here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33387368/740372

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all you should try to list your dependencies with `gradle :MODULE:dependencies` 
Check if there are libraries conflicts ( same library but different version ). In this case i supose you should exclude support library module from Facebook SDK.

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Comment: 15 and accept ? why ? this is my error when I put exclude : DSL NOT FOUND EXCLUDE

Answer (score 0):

While using Facebook SDK project library, Pawel's solution worked for me.

However it stopped working after I had migrated to Gradle dependency `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.1'`. Tried to rebuild/reopen project but nothing helped.

This worked for me:

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: this worked for me: `compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.1') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }`