# When trying to build my project I'm getting an error. Do anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the error that occurs in the Message Gradle Build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':ParseStarterProject:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
  org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
  'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with 
  non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: Please add whole error log..!! because this is only last error..!!

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: put your gradle code in your Q. It may be a dependecy build issue like this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028705/java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-when-using-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into your gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

It might be you enabled multiDex for release builds type only, not for debug builds.