# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

i've some error with my project. I'm Android beginner.
When I try to compile my app I get a following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I'm using Parse SDK for login with Facebook,but in this moment,i've only this code in my app:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // [Optional] Power your app with Local Datastore. For more info, go to
    // https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#local-datastore
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.initialize(this);
```

my build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.daniele.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}


  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}  
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
  }
```

How can I solve it?
First answer of this doesn't work for me: [java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2 when using Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028705/java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-when-using-facebook-sdk)
Many thanks.

EDIT:
I solved it,for now.
I deleted 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+' from dependecies and it works.
I don't know why,but in the parse's tutorial,it suggest to add all of this dependencies

Comment: Scroll higher in the Gradle console transcript, above where you have that error, and you will find the actual source of your problem.

Comment: I solved it,for now.
I deleted 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+' from dependecies and it works.
I don't know why,but in the parse's tutorial,it suggest to add all of this dependencies

Comment: Don't you need com.parse:parse-android:1.+ for Parse? When I deleted mine, I got a lot more compiler errors

Comment: Found cause and solution, at least for me, I added answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35045501/3397345

Answer (score 7):

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.minls.cmn"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
**dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"**
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

put just this line
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using **Oracle's JDK version 8** which is based on **Java 8** that is not *officially* supported by Android. More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23318269/3535408.

Some tweaks exist but I do not recommend them. Stick to **Java 7 and JDK 7** and you are good to go.

To change the JDK usage :
Go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location > and change the JDK for JDK 7. You can download last version of JDK 7 here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Once I tried to add a Java Library that was compiled using JDK 8 in another IDE (NetBeans). I did not use any Java 8 features such as lambdas in this library but it was enough for Gradle to complain. 
So back in NetBeans, I changed the settings so that it compiles with JDK 7 and there my problem was solved !

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

If the above error occurs in Spring Boot Gradle project, please restart your system and check again. It is due to the memory issue.