# Error Gradle Build C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is my gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.gerenciarsc.nfce"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'br.com.uol.ps:library:0.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'javax.xml.crypto:jsr105-api:1.0.1'
    compile ('commons-io:commons-io:2.4'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons.collections', module: 'org.apache.commons.collections'
    }    
}
```

Comment: look into the gradle console whats the exact error

Comment: set `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` // at first . The `Clean-Rebuild-Sync-Run` .Let me inform please .

Comment: set`minSdkVersion 15` .remove `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1''`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I performed all the changes you told me , but the error persists

Comment: @ArthurRodrigues same type library or version  mismatch creating this .

Comment: @ArthurRodrigues debug please . comment `com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core` one by one .

Comment: @ArthurRodrigues Did you solve yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya 
if I comment on these libraries , do not compile an application

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya MultiDex is enabled

Comment: It's enabled, but did you set it in the Application class?

Comment: Yes, in the Application class, I set code "MultiDex.install(this);"

Comment: I found this Git discussion helpful for me: https://github.com/facebook/rebound/issues/71

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug)

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue. Scrolling down, I found the following error in the logs:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Then I searched for the above error and found the following work-around as suggested by the solutions to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910550/problems-after-installing-java-8) and another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990995/com-android-dx-command-main-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0):

In the file build.gradle(Module:app) I changed the following from:

`buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"`

to

`buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`

and clicked the button to "sync project with gradle files" in Android Studio and the error vanished.

**Note**: I didn't understand the exact reason for the error and it's solution completely but it seems to be a compatibility issue of java version 1.7 and Android API level 24. Some people suggested (on the questions' links I mentioned) to use JDK version 8 with API 24, or downgrade it to JDK version 7 and API level 23.0.x as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Found cause and solution.

All at the sudden this happened, when I created a class with the same signature (package and name) in 2 different projects of my environment and started the App to try it. Got that message.

I discovered it by adding `multiDexEnabled true` and new error message appeared with duplicated class found.

So, I refactored the class (changed package name), also removed `multiDexEnabled` support as it was before, the App started.

Comment: Where to add this?

Comment: @SouravNanda, you can check the question for where to add `multiDexEnabled true`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue after did reach i got resolved. issue could be the classes folder not created under build directory while you build the project, the reason for that the project path may not correct. so you have to correct the project path and rebuild that it will work fine. java files should be under path \src\main\java for gradle proejct

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error:

> Execution failed for task
>   ':vvm:transformClassesWithDesugarForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting
>   process 'command 'E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe''

I've solved it by updating gradle from 4.4 to 5.4

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue after did reach i not resolved. instead of applied two approaches as follows:

Process 1: Update plugin with build.gradle

```
plugins {
id "com.github.ManifestClasspath" version "0.1.0-RELEASE"
}
```

Process 2: Update the JAVA path while executing the application inside the IDE

Still it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I changed buildToolVersion in build.gradle(module:app) to 23.0.2
then the app is running.