# problems after installing java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio had a popup telling updates was available after i run the SDK manager and started the Android Studio again I got another popoup that toke me to Androids website where it told me that I should upgrade to Java JDK 8 and JRE 8 after I did i got over 235 errors when try to run the debug. I uninstalled version 8 and reinstalled 7u80 JDK and JRE now I'm down to 34 errors. When I type java -version I get 1.8.073
here are all 35 errors.

```
    Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Here is the Gradel.build

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kim.printer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/StarIOPort3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/StarIO_Extension.jar')
}
```

Thanks for any help I have been working on this for 6 hours and I can get it to compile.

Comment: Check if the path to JDK is set correctly. You can do this in Android Studio by clicking on _File_ -> _Project Structure_ -> _SDK Location_ -> _JDK Location_. And change in you gradle build these lines:

`sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`
`targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`

Comment: I change the JDK location back to 7 and the sourceCompatibility/ targetCompatibility back to 1_7 after I got the 235 errors. leaving the JDK on 7 and changing to 1_8 i get this error. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> invalid source release: 1.8

Answer (score 20):

The problem is in the buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1' after changing it to '23.0.2' I no longer get errors.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36620618/369317 Basically newer build tools (24.x) seem to work with jdk 8.

Answer (score 7):

This problem occurs when you update to Android Studio to 2.0.

**To solve this problem:**

- Open `build.gradle` file
- Change `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc1"` to `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`

Happy coding.

Comment: Why **23.0.2**, and not **24.0.3**?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is related with your SDK, not with your JDK.
You can check your version information from

> Help > About > Show Details

You will get something like

> Xamarin.Android Version: 6.0.2.1 (Starter Edition) Android SDK:
>   X:\Android\android-sdk
>
> Supported Android versions:
>
> 4.0.3 (API level 15)
>
> 4.4 (API level 19)
>
> 6.0 (API level 23)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 24.4.1
>
> SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.0.1
>
> SDK Build Tools Version: 24 rc2
>
> Java SDK: X:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
>
> java version "1.7.0_71"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

If you are using preview tools for building ,then you will get similar errors all over.

**What to do now?**

> Tools -> SDK manager

1. Select all items in preview channels including `Android SDK build tools` with rev `24rc2` or `24rc4`(latest)
2. Click on `Delete 'n' packages`

**How to turn off preview channel**

1. In SDK manager, select

   > Tools > options
2. Uncheck `Enable preview tools`

**And what**

Back to your code  *Clean all* and *rebuild*

Comment: well said. I was looking for this for two days

Answer (score 0):

Using Android SDK Manager, I removed my last update of Android SDK Build-Tools v.25 remaining with the previous one: v.23.0.3....

...now it's working as it should do!!!