# Visual Studio :Emulator not found

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I can not able see debug target selector.

Also while opening main.axml file getting error message.

Connection to java renderer failed-
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Please guide get out of this error...

Comment: Resolved... earlier 1. but now while deploying project getting error Exception in thread "main" 
1>java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
1>Build FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

`Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` typically means to update your JDK to 1.8:

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585636/1048571 for further details and potential workarounds if you do not want to install JDK 1.8.