# Xamarin Forms, Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am having this issue with Xamarin Forms, when trying to run the application, please share your knowledge so that i can fix this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version
>   52.0  App.Droid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Visual Studio - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431896/xamarin-visual-studio-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 when rendering in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio)

Comment: Update your JDK to 1.8