# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in Visual Studio + Xamarin

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've recently installed Visual Studio with Xamarin.

When I want to run even not modified app, I'm getting error

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Screenshoot of SDK manager:
[image: SDK manager]

From android 7.0 (API 24) theres nothing installed.

When I remove this Android SDK Build tools 24.0.3 I get just "Deploy failed" without any error information.

Seems like Visual Studio is still trying to use the 24 API version. Should I switch to API version 23? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java Lang UnsupportedClassVersion Error in Xamarin Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457947/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion-error-in-xamarin-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to install the Java JDK 1.8. I would suggest removing 1.7 unless you need to use previous versions. The release notes for Xamarin.Android 7.0 have more information as well: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/

> Note: Xamarin.Android 7.0 requires JDK 1.8 to use the Android Nougat
>   (API 24) APIs. You can continue to use earlier versions of the JDK if
>   targeting earlier Android API levels:
>
> JDK 1.8 - up to API 24+ JDK 1.7 - up to API 23 JDK 1.6 - up to API 20
>   Additionally, a 64-bit version of the JDK is required to use custom
>   controls in the Android designer.

Comment: Thank you for response. I did what you said.
This might help others.
What I did was running Genymotion, then Visual Studio automatically saw and and let me run my app directly on external emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install JDK 1.8.. and change the path.. it will be work...