# Xamarin With Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I Have many problems with xamarin + visual studio + windows 10.

I've read several tutorials and even the Microsoft website but they all have several errors in my visual studio, I just have difficulties emulating my Android, and even after installing the indicated sdk packages I still carry on with many errors.

I would like to know if anyone has any manual where I can install xamarin with Visual Studio 2015 community correctly in windows 10.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a question specific to the errors?  It is difficult to get it all set up, but I don't know of any manual.  I spent several days, and I'm not currently using the emulator.

Comment: Yeah post some specifics, I've got VS Community 2015 on WIndows 10 running Xamarin, it was maybe a couple of hours to get running after installing a bunch of stuff. I don't remember the exact steps I took but I do remember it took a fair bit of googling, I think there were some nuget packages that I had to install manually, and also some other software outside of VS.

Comment: @SList i edit post and upload print.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the [Getting Started](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/) and [Accelerating Android Emulators with HAXM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/) (for Intel CPUs) guides on the Xamarin website.

If you're still having problems I would recommend posting again with more specific information on what issues you're experiencing.

Comment: I uninstalled my SDK and now I'm installing everything again, I'm very disappointed with the difficulty of installing this, sometimes it seems to be a dropped project.

Comment: The second screenshot shows "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0", which has been [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36458217/6146870): "The version 52.0 here is referring to the specific release of the JDK, which in this case relates to JDK 8. Xamarin.Android 7.0 requires JDK 1.8 to use the Android Nougat (API 24) APIs."

Comment: @ashley Thanks for help. But i have error on create windows.phone project

Comment: Hey @BelitaColares! Sorry to hear you're still having problems. Since this doesn't appear to be related to your original query you would be better served if you create a new question with the specific problem or error you're coming across. I hope that helps for now.