# Exporting google vr unity sdk master sample file from unity and getting error

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Exporting google vr unity SDK master sample file from unity and getting an error like Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.

Please see the complete error

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:127)
]
stdout[

]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of mismatch between the JDK necessary for the google vr sdk and yours. You might need to update your JDK and Android SDK.

This links found another workaround:

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910550/problems-after-installing-java-8)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990995/com-android-dx-command-main-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)