# Android gradle error unsupportedclassversionerror

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to make my first app (hello world) and run it on my phone, but when I click run, gradle returns this error(i researched here on stackoverflow and tried to turn off instant run but it doesn't seem to work in my case):

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 55.085 secs

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}'
```

later edit: i figured it has something to do with the java version, but i don't know how to update my android studio?

later edit2: i figured it out, i had an older jdk version installed on my computer and the latest android studio, thanks for the help. I just had to install the newest jdk version(8)

Comment: All fingers seem to point to build tools versioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910550/problems-after-installing-java-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990995/com-android-dx-command-main-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle(Module:app)
AS IS : buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
TO BE : buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

reference : https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html
[Build Tools, Revision 23.0.3 (March 2016)]

Comment: You should elaborate the answer