# snackbar in android fragment - onClickListener() build gradle fails

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-snackbar

I am trying to show snackbar when my fragment view is inflated. 
I have written the snackbar code in onViewCreated, it works and shows me the snackbar. But when I am trying to setAction and set onClickListener the Build gradle fails. I am attaching the code snippet and error log.

FragmentContact.java

```
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Doubt?", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Call",new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                })
             .show();
```

Error Log

```
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 44.306 secs
```

Dependencies in gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
}
```

Comment: can you edit the question with the code in gradle file?

Comment: Run gradlew assemble --info and post the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to

- Remove any duplicated for example

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
 compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"`
you already added

- Remove any unused dependencies for example 
  are you need this `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` all google play services. if you just need map you can add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0` not all service check the link for all google service https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
- Try to add `defaultConfig { // Enabling multidex support. multiDexEnabled true }` check the [Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)

Comment: Clean your project then build. if not work try to add `defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
` check the link (https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)

Comment: Also check this post have the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028705/java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-when-using-facebook-sdk)

Comment: Sally ! your workaround to add multiDexEnabled true worked for me! But is it recommended to go for it? since it has quiet a few drawbacks too!

Comment: its clear that you have problem in dependencies. remove any duplicated,  remove any unused dependencies, for example are you need this "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0" all google play services. if you just need map you can add " com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0" not all service check the link for all google service (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)