# Execution failed for task ':wittyfeednew:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'

Tags: android, exception, android-multidex

Execution failed for task ':wittyfeednew:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class

```
 dependencies {
    compile project(':titanic')
    compile project(':urlImageViewHelper')
    compile project(':socialauthandroid')
    compile project(':rippleLibrary')
    compile project(':loadMoreListView')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':circularImageView')
    compile project(':cardview')
    compile project(':staggeredGrid')
    compile project(':materialDesign')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')

    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/pinit-sdk-1.0-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/pinit-sdk-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

Comment: Remove compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar') and try because com.google.android.gms:play-services:+ contains all so

Comment: It's give error in my java file.

Comment: I guess u have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484034/execution-failed-for-task-packagealldebugclassesformultidex and https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#Setup

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful. Your question is of very poor quality.

Comment: not sure what is play-services:+
but if you want to access Plus API then you can include this :
com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0. Add this adn try. 
If that play-service:+ adds all services from gms then remove that and add the ones you only need. Follow this: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup