# gradle duplicate entry FloatProperty

Tags: android, debugging, gradle

I have add spinnerwheel module into my project and it wouldn't build anymore. It has some kind of a duplicate entry with nineoldandroids library Which is included in spinnerwheel  module  . I get this error during the build

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
    > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nineoldandroids/util/FloatProperty.class
```

I ran `../gradlew dependencies` on the app folder and this is what i found under spinnerwheel module:

```
\--- *********-android3.5:spinnerwheel:unspecified
     \--- LOCAL: nineoldandroids-2.2.0.jar
```

This is my build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.1'
    compile project(':loopj')
    compile project(':StackBlur')
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:+'
    compile 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.6.3'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.3'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.11'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-appmsg:appmsg:1.2.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.5.5'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.2.8'
}
```

Comment: show your app gradle ..It seems you have added a library 2 times

Comment: i have add a link to it

Comment: Can you try this ,look like the same issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718825/how-to-resolve-java-util-zip-zipexception

Comment: post your build.gradle here

Comment: Does the lib folder contain the nineoldandroids jar?

Comment: At first update this minifyEnabled false

Comment: Gabriele Mariotti yes

Comment: nineoldandroids-2.2.0 too old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just Add this `compile 'compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'` in your gradle section And update `minifyEnabled false` instead `minifyEnabled true` [Like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016385/error26-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard/27342403#27342403)

Comment: should i remove the jar from the module ?

Comment: Yes . gradle your project & restart . Happy coding