# Gradle build error in android studio with appcompact library

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':yourapp:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/recyclerview/BuildConfig.class
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile (project(':library_slidingmenu')) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.0'
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Someone have already answered...Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718825/how-to-resolve-java-util-zip-zipexception)

Comment: @roccocullo.Two errors are not exactly same.

Comment: Please post the results of `gradle androidDependencies`.  You have conflicting dependencies and probably need to exclude a module but without the dependency graph its hard to say which

Comment: Are you including `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.0'` as a dependency in either `project(':library_slidingmenu')` or `project(':library')`?

Comment: @JBirdVegas one of the library has dependency of `recyclerview`

Comment: @Soham I think that's enough info to solve the problem.  See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dependency that also declares the `recyclerview` lib then just exclude it from the dependency.  For example imagine your lib `library_slidingmenu` contains the `recyclerview` dependency, then we would need to do something like this

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library_slidingmenu') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    // the rest of your dependecies
}
```

Comment: Then more info is needed post the results `gradle androidDependencies` as previously asked

Comment: By the way one thing has been solved,that it's not repeating.Sometimes I have to clean and build it again,then it's running.So I am accepting your answer.