# Issue:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, dependencies

**Error** 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/collect/package-info.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "gravitykerala.in.donateblood"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/raw'] } }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.tibolte:agendacalendarview:1.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

this on first line

Comment: Its added ,its  missed while copy paste

Comment: @SreejithVs  go through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718825/how-to-resolve-java-util-zip-zipexception

Answer (score 0):

**this dependency was outdated**

compile 'com.github.tibolte:agendacalendarview:1.0.3'