# Amazon IAP v2.0 don't responde on android live testing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I implemented Amazon IAP v2.0 on android application, on start of application I register PurchasingService, and call

```
    PurchasingService.getUserData();
    PurchasingService.getPurchaseUpdates(true);
```

And all is working while working in *Amazon App Tester*, but when I use *Amazon Live Testing* PurchasingService don't give any response (callbacks are not called : `onUserDataResponse(), onPurchaseUpdatesResponse()`). Also I used all specification for Proguard , and registered ResponseReceiver in manifest.
All implementation was done using [tutorial on amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/implementing-iap-2.0).
In logs i have seen something like

```
D/AmazonBillingHelper﹕ checking isSubscriptionActive
D/AmazonBillingHelper﹕ currentSubscription is null
```

But I didnt implement `AmazonBillingHelper`

Also in log I found that there are some default listeners that ovveride my, is it ok ?

```
 D/Kiwi﹕ In App Purchasing SDK - Production Mode: d: PurchasingListener registered: com.my.package
 D/Kiwi﹕ In App Purchasing SDK - Production Mode: d: PurchasingListener registered: com.washingtonpost.android.paywall.billing.amazon.AmazonIAPListener
```

As I investigated this `com.washingtonpost.android.paywall.billing.amazon.AmazonIAPListener` is from *Amazon App Tester*, deleted it, but anyway it's not working

It's possible that it is connected with multidex build.
Main dex should contain :

> Custom, Applications, Activities, Services, Receivers, Providers,
> Instrumentations, Annotations

specification from amazon [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx291UO6WP91P9Z/Too-Many-Methods-How-to-Avoid-Compile-Errors-on-Submission)  and problem solving method on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614095/using-gradle-to-split-external-libraries-in-separated-dex-files-to-solve-android)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Amazon App Test don't full fill requirements from live testing. Because generally if you call any request from `onCreate()` while testing in Sandbox - you'll receive response. On Live testing you should initialize listener in onCrate() but call any methods from `onResume()`.

Comment: did that finally solve it for you? i'm still experiencing this problem even when separating the calls between onResume and onCreate. it's also not clear if one should be creating a global listener at the application level or if one should do it at the activity level (like Google In-App API). you do have to specify the application context when registering the listener so i assume it's the former.